# HTTP Archive Specification

Tags: performance, web, pagespeed, http-archive

I want to know **webpage** performance of given **URL**, 
Specifically time difference (between request and response) of each resource used in given webpage (URL).

Google Page Speed API does the same, but it requires [*.HAR](http://groups.google.com/group/http-archive-specification?hl=en)  file as input, I don’t know ***how to generate*** HAR File for given URL.

Can you please guide me; I want to integrate this functionality to my existing **WPF** application.

Is there any tool will generate html URL to HAR?

Thanks,
Hiren Shah.

Answer (score 1):

from the [spec](http://groups.google.com/group/http-archive-specification/web/har-1-2-spec):

> - The format is based on JSON.

so i guess you could just generate an array/object using whatever language you're using then convert it to JSON. most languages have a library/functions for this.

or you could use one of [these tools](http://groups.google.com/group/http-archive-specification/web/har-adopters?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks But I'm afraid that i want to develop system using WPF Window (.NET), 
I cannot use Chrome or Firefox & add-in, 
As i mentioned earlier, Google Page Speed API does the same, but it 
requires *.HAR file as 
input, I don’t know how to generate HAR File for given PRIVATE URL.

Most of these tools are not free (open source) or require public URL or HAR File.

Comment: Is there any tool will generate html URL to HAR?

Answer (score 1):

Tools you could use to generate a HAR in IE include:

Proxies

1. Fiddler
2. BrowserMob Proxy
3. Charles Proxy ($)

Browser plugins

1. HTTP Watch ($)
2. Dynatrace AJAX Edition

The proxies will have some impact on the timing as they're essentially a 'man-in-the-middle', if you can afford it HTTP watch would be my recommendation.

I have a soft spot for Charles as it really is a powerful tool and allows you to inspect HTTPS traffic too.

Answer (score 1):

From [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome) launch the developer tools <kbd>F12</kbd> and switch to the "Net" tab.  This probably gives you the data you want, but you can also export a `.har` file.  Right click on a column title (Name, Method etc..) and you can choose "Copy all as HAR" or "Save all as HAR...".

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page : [HTML to HAR](https://github.com/Filirom1/browsermob-page-perf)

It is written in Java using the selenium API, and there is a Selenium API in .NET
This project is very small : two files, so it will be easy for you to understand and translate it in .NET